# cannot load such file -- ../helpers/ping

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a class in my `ruby` app, let's call it `ping`
and i have put this class in the `app/helpers` folder. I am trying to require this class to my controller using this code:

```
require '../helpers/ping'

class PingController < ApplicationController
    def index
     end
end
```

but the problem is, when i load the index view, it complains with the error:

```
cannot load such file -- ../helpers/ping
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as following without file path:

```
require 'ping'
```

OR

```
require_relative 'helpers/ping'
```

Comment: Yes, but can youdescribe, how it works? it seems that **../helpers/ping **
should be true?

Comment: `require` will search for files in only a set of locations referred to as the **"Load Path."** You can view the load path by using the global variable `$LOAD_PATH` in a script or irb session. If it is not in the load path, it won't find it.